# Replacement of existing carpet and vinyl tile fllors

Tags: flooring

I am planning on doing a major Reno to my main floor this year and am looking for guidance on how to do the flooring.

I currently have vinyl peel & stick tiles in the hallway and kitchen. This was applied over the original builders 12 x 12 faux marble tile (circa 1975).  The L-shaped LR/DR is carpeted.

I want to install engineered hardwood in the LR/DR/hallway and ceramic in the kitchen.  I will likely also be replacing kitchen cabinetry, in case that should be a consideration in my approach to this reno.

This project leaves me in need of advice regarding how to remove the old vinyl floor, and if I cut through the underlay to do that (which seems like the easiest way, though there is a possibility of asbestos in the builder’s tile) should I remove the underlay from the carpeted areas before laying the engineered hardwood.

I hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance for any advice offered.

Comment: Welcome, Jackie. Please know that we are not a discussion forum, and you're obligated to ask a more specific question. Please revise to make it clear what you're asking. See the help pages for more information.

Comment: Not near enough info, please supply type of subfloor, how you intend to fasten the wood, (glue, float, staple down). What the vinyl attached to ( subfloor, underlayment), if underlayment then what kind.
The variables involved in this is huge, and all job conditions vary. Pictures help also.